# jcmd - What is command ManagementAgent.start used for?

Tags: java, jvm, jcmd

When using `jcmd` to monitor java process, there is a command `ManagementAgent.start`.

Checking man page / oracle document / google, didn't found any description.

**The question is:**

- What is it used for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This command starts remote JMX agent as if `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote` command-line argument is set. See [Monitoring and Management Using JMX Technology](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html).

Answer (score 3):

**ManagementAgent.stop:** Stop remote management agent.

**ManagementAgent.start:** Start remote management unit

**ManagementAgent.start_local:** Start local management agent.

You can get an example at below link.

https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2018/08/jcmd-managementagentstop.html

Answer (score 0):

The `ManagementAgent` commands of jcmd will call methods of the `jdk.internal.agent.Agent` class on the target JVM:

- `start` calls `startRemoteManagementAgent()`,
- `start_local` calls `startLocalManagementAgent()`,
- `stop` calls `stopRemoteManagementAgent()`,
- `status` calls `getManagementAgentStatus()`.

Basically, what the first two do is start a JMX connector server (each with different parameters) for the platform MBean server of the target JVM. The `status` command is useful to get information about the running JMX agents.

Source code for `start_local`: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/hotspot/share/services/diagnosticCommand.cpp#L736